# Which devices can run iOS 8?

Tags: ios

Has Apple released a list of which devices are capable of running iOS 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Apple has released the [compatible device list](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios8/) (see the bottom) :

- iPhone 4s
- iPhone 5
- iPhone 5c
- iPhone 5s
- iPod touch 5th generation
- iPad 2
- iPad with Retina display (iPad 3)
- iPad Air
- iPad mini
- iPad mini with Retina display

Answer (score 5):

It's at the bottom of the [public iOS 8 page](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios8/) where it states the 10 models of hardware to be supported:

- **iPhone 4s**, **iPhone 5**, **iPhone 5c** and **iPhone 5s**
- **iPad 2**, **iPad with Retina display**, **iPad Air**
- **iPad Mini** and **iPad Mini with Retina display**
- **iPod Touch (5th Generation)**